# Symfony 5+ - How to set a sizeable amount of routes as public (no auth)

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5, symfony6

In my project there are a lot of routes, some of them public, some not. Is there a elegant way to set a good amount of routes as public?

I'm currently using a custom RequestMatcher, like:

```
final class RequestMatcher implements RequestMatcherInterface
{
    private const PUBLIC_ROUTES = [
        '/img/.*',
        '/v1/page/loading.*',
        '/v1/page2/[^/]+/success.*',
        //...15 more routes
    ];

    public function matches(Request $request): bool
    {
        $pattern = '~^(?:' . implode('|', self::PUBLIC_ROUTES) . ')$~';
        if (preg_match($pattern, $request->getPathInfo())) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

and in the security.yml

```
security:
    firewalls:
        public:
            request_matcher: App\Security\RequestMatcher
            security: false
        api:
            pattern: ^/
            stateless: true
            provider: hmac
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - my_hmac_authenticator
```

but this is not a perfect solution since the RequestMatcher has a list that has to be maintained separately from the controller and the matcher is kind of quirky when dealing with trailing slashes.

Is there a better way to handle this case?

Comment: Why not use `access_control` setting in your `security.yml`? Also, if you use Symfony 5 or later, why did you tag this question with [tag:symfony4]? Keep in mind that version-specific tags should only be used if the question is related to that specific version

Comment: @NicoHaase `access_control` is used for authorization, not authentication. And even if it could be used, it would also create a separate list of routes that should be maintained. Thanks for the tip about the tags, I removed the symfony4 tag from the question.

Comment: I use `access_control` with `PUBLIC_ACCESS` a lot. Also, yeah, you need to keep this list anywhere. Maybe setting `#[IsGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')]` on the **private** routes instead could help?